# Loop over directory of files, and perform operation on them

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

I have my loop working:

```
for indice, file_path in enumerate(all_current_files):
    print("indice {} filepath {} indice+1 {}".format(indice, file_path, indice + 1))
```

This outputs:

```
indice 0 filepath /path/here/img.jpg indice+1: 1
```

I want to use this current `for()` loop, and for each file *compare* `indice1`'s path to `indice2`'s path(the next one).

For example:

```
1 my/path/img.jpg
2 my/path/img.jpg
```

I want to include a little comparison.

I am having trouble formulating how I might do this.

Comment: The output doesn't match what your code is going. Both `indice` and `indice + 1` show up as `1`

Comment: What do you mean. Understand `indice+1` is performing a calculation. So if original indice is `1` then new one is `2`

Comment: Your output is `indice 1 filepath /path/here/img.jpg indice+1: 1` seems like it should be `indice 0 filepath /path/here/img.jpg indice+1: 1`

Comment: Excuse the typo that is the case. Can you help me my question please

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's one way to do it. I'm sure there are many others.

```
prevpath = None
for indice, path in enumerate(path_list):
    if prevpath is not None:
        print("prevpath={}, path={}".format(prevpath, element))
        # do compare here
    prevpath = element
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, (currentpath, prevpath) in enumerate(zip(all_current_files[1:], all_current_files[:-1])):
    print("i={} previous='{}'  current='{}'".format(i, prevpath, currentpath))
```

In the above code `i` is the index of the "current" path. If you need this to start at 1, simply set the `start` parameter of the `enumerate` function.

If you want to get indices of both current and previous paths, do the following:

```
for (i, currentpath), (j, prevpath) in zip(enumerate(all_current_files[1:], 1), enumerate(all_current_files[:-1])):
    print("i={} previous='{}'   j={} current='{}'".format(i, prevpath, j, currentpath))
```

Replace `print` in the loop with whatever computations you need to be done.